# Casting shadow without any floor

Tags: tracking

So I wanted to render a my model in a video scene, and after setting up the tracking scene I can see that in render view, both the model and the floor are visible (along with the shadow casted). What I wanna do is that I wanna make the floor invisible ( i.e., blend in with the actual scene )[image], but then the shadow disappears too. Is there any way of casting the shadow without the floor?

Comment: Explore "Shadow Catcher". https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89671/shadow-catcher-makes-background-objects-invisible

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87286/add-object-and-shadow-over-a-background-using-the-compositor/87314#87314