# How to make shadow catcher object invisible in mirror?

Tags: mirror, shadows, shadowcatcher

I modified and added this car model to my scene but it was having no side mirrors. So I made mirror plane and added mirror material to it but to cast car shadows on HDRI, I used shadow catcher object which is visible in mirror. How do I make the shadow catcher object invisible in mirror also?

Here's render preview:
[image]

Comment: You need to select the plane (shadow Catcher), then go to Object Properties > Visibility. there you will find a "glossy" checkbox that you need to uncheck

Comment: @Emir this makes no sense, because than you won't see the shadows in the mirror....

Comment: Take a look at this answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89671/shadow-catcher-makes-background-objects-invisible.